# Design pattern for progress monitoring using Observables

Tags: java, observable, rx-java

I have a java method that performs **asynchronous item processing** and returns an `Observable`.

I would like to **provide progress monitoring** information to the caller.

The first thing that comes in mind is to return a **second `Observable`** and add them both into a wrapper class.

Is there **any other way or best-practice** I could use to provide progress monitoring functionality using Observables?

Answer (score 2):

First thing that comes in my mind is the `timestamp` operator whitch returns an Observable of `Timed<T>`

```
@CheckReturnValue
@SchedulerSupport(SchedulerSupport.NONE)
public final Observable<Timed<T>> timestamp() {
    return timestamp(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, Schedulers.computation());
}
```

You can do somthing similar and wrap your object on a `Progress` object like:

```
public final class Progress<T> {
  final int percent;
  final T value
}
```

`value` is your original object and `percent` is the value of the progress